# Is the SOAP webservice API availiable in the SSRS 2008 express edition?

Tags: web-services, reporting-services

In other words, if I set up SSRS Express edition will I be able to consume and make calls through the webservice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Check this link on features supported. [Reporting Services in SQL Server Express with Advanced Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166.aspx).

Your best best is the Express edition with Advanced Services.

[SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B5D1B8C3-FDA5-4508-B0D0-1311D670E336&displaylang=en) has all of the features in SQL Server 2008 Express, plus you can:

Run SQL Server Reporting Services reports on local relational data.